# Isomorphisms between isometry groups of maximally symmetric spaces

Tags: general-relativity, group-theory

For maximally symmetric spaces in a given dimension, $d$, and a given signature, it is my understanding that there are always three distinctive cases, according to whether the scalar curvature is positive, negative or equally zero. My question is, is there a group isomorphism between the isometry groups of those spaces?

For example, in 4 spacetime dimensions in Lorentzian signature (+---), are ISO(4), SO(4) and SO(2,2) isomorphic?

Comment: $SO(4)$ is an isometry group of 3-sphere, $S^3$. If the signature is $(+,-,-,-)$ then the groups are $SO(1,4)$ for dS${}_4$, $SO(2,3)$ for AdS${}_4$ and $ISO(1,3)$ for $M_4$.

Comment: You are right, I got them all completely wrong, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $\mathrm{SO}(4)$ is semisimple and compact,
- $\mathrm{ISO}(4)$ is not semisimple nor compact (has an $\mathbb{R}^4$ subgroup that is abelian),
- $\mathrm{SO}(2,2)$ is semisimple and not compact (the "rapidity" angles of the boosts vary in a non-compact space).

So there cannot be an isomorphism betweeen any two of them.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense of course! What could be then the shared properties between those groups? Maybe just having the same number of generators? d(d+1)/2?

Comment: Yes, since they correspond to the same sort of set of Killing vectors. Also all those groups have the same dimensions for the generators acting freely on the manifold, since they need to have the same number of generators of translation/rotation.

Comment: A related concept is the [Inonu contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_contraction) perhaps? It does not apply exactly, but it came to my mind.

Comment: @MannyC It is a very interesting idea, it is indeed along the lines of what I was trying to find. It is natural that both AdS and dS groups tend to the flat case as curvature grows, but I wonder if there could be a more "general" algebra for which all three cases are particular limits.

Comment: It could be interesting to know if an algebra expressible like $[A,B]=\epsilon_1 C_1 + \epsilon_2 C_2$ could be consistent and have an AdS limit when $\epsilon_1 \to 0$, a dS limit when $\epsilon_2 \to 0$ and a flat limit when both tend to zero. But I guess group theory is a very well researched area and I have never heard of such construction, so I suspect an algebra like that does not close? Should I ask this in another question in case someone may know about such a construction?

Comment: Yeah, I don't have any candidates off the top of my head. You could try asking a question, but perhaps there's the risk of it being too vague.